# How do I get pyinstaller to work correctly to convert my files?

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

For some reason, I cannot get pyinstaller to work.

I did:

`pip install pyinstaller`

and then did:

`pyinstaller` in terminal

this is the error I got

`'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.`

How do I fix this?

I am using:

1. Python 3.8 (From Microsoft Store)
2. Pyinstaller 4.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to restart the terminal between installation and launch ?

Comment: According to their webpage you run, pyinstaller yourprogram.py see, https://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: It might be because of the Microsoft store version, have you tried with python installer from python.org site.. just try **pip /?** in cmd abd check it is working or not...

Comment: Try `python -m pyinstaller`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you've a messed up environment, maybe with multiple python versions.
Check your default python, pip and PyInstaller module versions + system path with:

```
where python
where pip
pip show pyinstaller
set path
```

The pip command should be located on a Script subfolder of python, and pyinstaller on a lib\site-packages subfolder.
Also, take a look the the path variable: if it does not contain the folder where pyinstaller is located you will not be able to run it without specifying its full path.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the reviews on python 3.8 in MS store, a reviewer said pyinstaller isn't working for them. So idk if it may be the type of python.exe that I am using or my windows machine is a little restrictive.

I also heard pyinstaller has errors with 3.5+ and works better with python 2.7